# Visual Studio Code choosing a default Org

Tags: vs-code, vscode-dx

How do I choose a default org to connect to? I see a few but no option to choose which one?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the "SFDX: Set a Default Org" command from the command palette in VSCode, focus for the cursor is retained by the command palette. So just start typing one of the possible org names, and VSCode will start filtering the possible choices.

Alternatively, if you click that last line listing all of the orgs you've authorized, you should subsequently be given the option to pick a specific one of them.

If you end up choosing the wrong org, you can always run the command again.

There's also the option of setting that via the command line, e.g.
`sfdx config:set defaultusername=derekf@myorg.tld` or `sfdx config:set defaultusername=<OrgAlias>`

Comment: Thank you! That worked!